# Двумерные массивы в C++Builder, область видимости

Tags: c++, c++builder

Как получить доступ к `List` для обработки его другими функциями (кнопками)?

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   if (!OpenDialog1->Execute()) return;

   TStringList *list = new TStringList();
   list->LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1->FileName);
   delete list;
}
```

Comment: Почему бы не сделать его членом класса TForm1?

Comment: И я не вижу двумерных массивов в предоставленном вами фрагменте кода.:)

Comment: Не знаю, как это сделать. С классами мало работал. Процедурный стиль использовал.

Comment: Я не имел дело с этой библиотекой Borland , которая называется, если я не ошибаюсь, VCL, но, думаю, что TForm1 - это производный класс от TForm. Вам надо в этот производный класс добавить новый член и, кончено, правильно с ним работать. Например, конструктор должен его инициализировать, наверное, значением NULL, а деструктор должен его удалить.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, достаточно просто определить член класса TForm1

```
TStringList *list;
```

и использовать его в других методах класса, если в этом есть необходимость.

Вы можете сделать этот член класса закрытым:

```
private:
    TStringList *list;
```